# 403 "rest_forbidden" error in WordPress REST API

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to setup a REST API on my Wordpress site but I keep getting a:
403 "rest_forbidden","message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to do that." 
message
on both a normal user and also my administrator account.

I just don't get it.

I've tried to do my homework at read different articles on the matter and I've come to the conclusion that my users don't have the "manage_options" permission.
Even the administrator and that is a puzzel for me as it should be granted as a standard.

I've tried to fix the error by following the 2 articles:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/348231/how-do-i-correctly-setup-an-ajax-nonce-for-wordpress-rest-api/348239#348239

[403 "rest_forbidden" error in WordPress REST API (but only for settings)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45931189/403-rest-forbidden-error-in-wordpress-rest-api-but-only-for-settings)

I need some help!!!

My JS code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
        json/agility_body_reactions/v1/exercise_data_submits',
        url: 'https://MySite.dk/wp-json/agility/v1/body_reactions_exercise_submits/',
        method: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(
                'X-WP-Nonce',
                wpApiSettings.nonce );
        },
        data: {
                gender: gender,
                age: age,
                minutes: minutes,
                seconds: seconds
        }
});
```

My Register Endpoint code looks like this:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_endpoint_body_reaction');
function register_endpoint_body_reaction()
{
    register_rest_route(
        'agility/v1',
        '/body_reactions_exercise_submits/',

        array(
            'methods' => 'POST',
            'callback' => 'callback_body_reaction',
            'args' => array(
                'age' => array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'validate_callback' => function($param, $request) {
                        return is_numeric( $param) and ! is_null( $param);
                    },
                    'sanitize_callback' => 'absint'
                ),
                'minutes' => array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'validate_callback' => function($param, $request) {
                        return is_numeric( $param) and ! is_null( $param);
                    },
                    'sanitize_callback' => 'absint'
                )
            )
           ,
            'permission_callback' => function() {
                if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
                    return new WP_Error( 'Unauthorized', 'Sorry, but your not logged in...fll', array( 'status' => 401 ) );
                }
            }
        )
    );
}
```

My Enqueue Scripts code looks like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_js_body_reaction');
function enqueue_js_body_reaction()
{
    if (!is_page('agility-body-reaction')) {
        return;
    }

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'agility_body_reaction',
        plugins_url( '../js/agility_body_reaction.js', __FILE__ ),
        array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-core' ),
        AGILITY_BODY_REACTION_VERSION,
        true
    );

    wp_localize_script(
        'agility_body_reaction',
        'wpApiSettings',
        array(
            'root'  => esc_url_raw( rest_url() ),
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ),
        )
    );
}
```

So my questions are:

1. How do I get the right permissions "manage_option" added to the users?
2. The "manage_option" seem a lot of right to grant a normal user even if it is for a short time isn't there another way to run the REST API with just normal subscriber permissions?

Thanks.
Flemming

UPDATE!
I added some code to my Registre Endpoint Permission_callback:

```
if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
                    return new WP_Error( 'Unauthorized', 'Sorry, but you dont have the manage_options permissions...fll', array( 'status' => 401 ) );
                }
```

I then tried the REST API with my admin & with the normal user.

The Admin gets a 403 which means it has the "manage_options" set.
The normal user gets the above message which means it has no "manage_options set."

I guess this means that there are some other issue with my REST API.
I still need to know how to enable the "manage_options" for a normal user though.

UPDATE!
I read in some articles that the .htaccess could create an "403 Forbidden" but I'm really not familiar with this file. I'm quite desperate so I'll post the .htaccess configuration.

```
# BEGIN Really Simple SSL Redirect 5.3.0
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END Really Simple SSL Redirect
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress


# Wordfence WAF
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
php_value auto_prepend_file '/var/www/<MySite>/public_html/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
php_value auto_prepend_file '/var/www/<MySite>/public_html/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
# END Wordfence WAF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error.

The code with is_user_logged_in had an error.

```
'permission_callback' => function() {
     if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
          return new WP_Error( 'Unauthorized', 'Sorry, but your not logged in...fll', array( 'status' => 401 ) );
     }
 }
```

It should have logged like this:

```
'permission_callback' => function() {
     return is_user_logged_in();
 }
```

So all the code besides this works as it should for the cookie based authentication.